# Add new Outlook contact to autocomplete using EWS?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, exchangewebservices

I successfully added a new Contact to a users Outlook address book using the following code:

```
Contact contact = new Contact(_service);
contact.GivenName = firstName;
contact.Surname = lastName;
contact.DisplayName = string.Format("{0} {1}", firstName, lastName);
contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1] = email;
contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1].Address = email;
contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1].Name = string.Format("{0} {1}", firstName, lastName);
contact.PhoneNumbers[PhoneNumberKey.PrimaryPhone] = phoneNumber;
contact.CompanyName = companyName;
contact.NickName = string.Format("{0} {1}", firstName, lastName);

contact.Save();
```

However, the new contact is not showing in the autocomplete list when creating a new email message for the 'to' field. If I manually create a new contact in Outlook autocomplete picks up the new contact and they'll display in the list. Is there a way to use EWS to add this new contact to that autocomplete list? I am using Outlook 2010

Answer (score 0):

No, EWS doesn't update the nickname cache. There's more information on this here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff625288.aspx.